# Sign a pdf file in Go (Golang) using digitorus/pdfsign

Tags: go, pdf, digital-signature, x509, pkcs#12

In go (golang) I need to sign a pdf document, but unlike other languages there are no libraries that make the job easier. I have found a couple of paid ones but they are not an option.

To start, I have a PKCS certificate (.p12) from which I already extract the private key and the x509 certificate using this package: https://pkg.go.dev/software.sslmate.com/src/go-pkcs12

But when I want to sign the pdf document I am stuck, because I don't know how to correctly pass the parameters to the function that performs such an action. The package used is https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/digitorus/pdfsign

My complete code is:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/digitorus/pdf"
    "github.com/digitorus/pdfsign/revocation"
    "github.com/digitorus/pdfsign/sign"
    gopkcs12 "software.sslmate.com/src/go-pkcs12"
)

func main() { 
    certBytes, err := os.ReadFile("certificate.p12") 

    if err != nil { 
        fmt.Println(err) 
        return
    }

    privateKey, certificate, chainCerts, err := gopkcs12.DecodeChain(certBytes, "MyPassword")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    input_file, err := os.Open("input-file.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer input_file.Close()
        
    output_file, err := os.Create("output-file.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer output_file.Close()
    
    finfo, err := input_file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    size := finfo.Size()
    
    rdr, err := pdf.NewReader(input_file, size)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    err = sign.Sign(input_file, output_file, rdr, size, sign.SignData{
    Signature: sign.SignDataSignature{
        Info: sign.SignDataSignatureInfo{
            Name:        "John Doe",
            Location:    "Somewhere on the globe",
            Reason:      "My season for siging this document",
            ContactInfo: "How you like",
            Date:        time.Now().Local(),
        },
        CertType:   sign.CertificationSignature,
        DocMDPPerm: sign.AllowFillingExistingFormFieldsAndSignaturesPerms,
        },
        Signer:            privateKey,    // crypto.Signer
        DigestAlgorithm:   crypto.SHA256, // hash algorithm for the digest creation
        Certificate:       certificate,   // x509.Certificate
        CertificateChains: chainCerts,    // x509.Certificate.Verify()
        TSA: sign.TSA{
            URL:      "https://freetsa.org/tsr",
            Username: "",
            Password: "",
        },

        // The follow options are likely to change in a future release
        //
        // cache revocation data when bulk signing
        RevocationData: revocation.InfoArchival{},
        // custom revocation lookup
        RevocationFunction: sign.DefaultEmbedRevocationStatusFunction,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Signed PDF written to output.pdf")
    }
}
```

To be exact, they are Signer and CertificateChains parameters my problem. I don't know how to use correctly privateKey and chainCerts variables.

The messages error are:

- cannot use privateKey (variable of type interface{}) as crypto.Signer value in struct literal: interface{} does not implement crypto.Signer (missing method Public)
- cannot use chainCertificates (variable of type []*x509.Certificate) as [][]*x509.Certificate value in struct literal

I am a newbie to this language, so I still do not know in-depth concepts and data types.

I thank you for telling me what else I should do or the steps that are missing to reach a successful conclusion. Or if anyone knows how I can sign a pdf based on a pkcs certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signing a PDF using a digital signature consists of using public key cryptography to generate a pair of keys. A private key is used to encrypt signature-related data and only the signer must have access to it and a public key which is used to decrypt the signature data for verification purposes, if not issued by a Trusted Certificate Authority, said public key certificate must be added to the certificate store for it to be trusted.
In the given example this signature data is stored inside a structure called sign.SignData which is part of the pdfsign library and expects a x509 certificate and a signer that implements crypto.Signer interface.

**The first step** is to use the crypto/ecdsa package from the Go standard library to generate a pair of keys. GenerateKey will save the private and public key into the privateKey variable.This returned privateKey variable implements crypto.Signer interface which is required to solve the issues you are currently facing.

You can check this by reading the ecdsa.go code, line 142.

- https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/ecdsa/ecdsa.go

You are currently using gopkcs12.DecodeChain which returns a private key, but it doesn't implement crypto.Signer interface hence the error. You probably would need to implement a custom one, but that is another question.

Concepts:

*ECDSA* stands for Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm. It is a public-key cryptography algorithm used for digital signatures. Please refer to the Go standard library documentation and to the NIST website for more information.

- https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/ecdsa@go1.21.4
- https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/ecdsa

NIST *P-384*: The P-384 is one of the recommended elliptic curves by the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) and has a 384-bit key length. Please refer to the NIST website for more information about digital signatures and more recommended elliptic curves. I used P-384 for the working solution.

- https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf
- https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/elliptic-curve-cryptography
- https://csrc.nist.gov/pubs/fips/186-4/fina

**The second step** is to use crypto/x509 package from the Go standard library to generate a x509 certificate and a certificate chain with its chain builder. These are the specific variables that you asked for help in your question and are not of the expected type as you can clearly see in the error messages. Just follow the lib instruction and use x509.Certificate.Verify() as I did in the working solution, this will return you the correct type [][]*x509.Certificate.

Please refer to the Go standard library documentation for more information.

- https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#Certificate.Verify
- https://golang.google.cn/pkg/crypto/x509/
- https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#Certificate

**The third step** is to open the input pdf file and create the output pdf file using the os package from the Go standard library.

**The fourth step** is actually signing the pdf file by using digitorus/pdfsign library.

This is a working solution I coded and tested today to get you back on track, do some research and modify to your needs:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/digitorus/pdf"
    "github.com/digitorus/pdfsign/revocation"
    "github.com/digitorus/pdfsign/sign"
    "log"
    "math/big"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // First step

    privateKey, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P384(), rand.Reader)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Second step

    x509RootCertificate := &x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: big.NewInt(2023),
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Organization:  []string{"Your Organization"},
            Country:       []string{"Your Country"},
            Province:      []string{"Your Province"},
            Locality:      []string{"Your Locality"},
            StreetAddress: []string{"Your Street Address"},
            PostalCode:    []string{"Your Postal Code"},
        },
        NotBefore:             time.Now(),
        NotAfter:              time.Now().AddDate(10, 0, 0),
        IsCA:                  true,
        ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth, x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth},
        KeyUsage:              x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature | x509.KeyUsageCertSign,
        BasicConstraintsValid: true,
    }

    rootCertificateBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, x509RootCertificate, x509RootCertificate, &privateKey.PublicKey, privateKey)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    rootCertificate, err := x509.ParseCertificate(rootCertificateBytes)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    roots := x509.NewCertPool()

    roots.AddCert(rootCertificate)

    certificateChain, err := rootCertificate.Verify(x509.VerifyOptions{
        Roots: roots,
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Third step

    outputFile, err := os.Create("output.pdf")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func(outputFile *os.File) {
        err = outputFile.Close()

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("output file closed")
    }(outputFile)

    inputFile, err := os.Open("input.pdf")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func(inputFile *os.File) {
        err = inputFile.Close()

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("input file closed")
    }(inputFile)

    fileInfo, err := inputFile.Stat()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    size := fileInfo.Size()

    pdfReader, err := pdf.NewReader(inputFile, size)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Fourth step

    err = sign.Sign(inputFile, outputFile, pdfReader, size, sign.SignData{
        Signature: sign.SignDataSignature{
            Info: sign.SignDataSignatureInfo{
                Name:        "Your name",
                Location:    "Your location",
                Reason:      "Your reason",
                ContactInfo: "Your contact info",
                Date:        time.Now().Local(),
            },
            CertType:   sign.CertificationSignature,
            DocMDPPerm: sign.AllowFillingExistingFormFieldsAndSignaturesPerms,
        },
        Signer:            privateKey,       // crypto.Signer
        DigestAlgorithm:   crypto.SHA256,    // hash algorithm for the digest creation
        Certificate:       rootCertificate,  // x509.Certificate
        CertificateChains: certificateChain, // x509.Certificate.Verify()
        TSA: sign.TSA{
            URL:      "",
            Username: "",
            Password: "",
        },

        // The follow options are likely to change in a future release
        //
        // cache revocation data when bulk signing
        RevocationData: revocation.InfoArchival{},
        // custom revocation lookup
        RevocationFunction: sign.DefaultEmbedRevocationStatusFunction,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("pdf signed")
    }
}
```

Result:

```
go run main.go

2023/12/01 21:53:37 pdf signed
input file closed
output file closed
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The messages error are:

- cannot use privateKey (variable of type interface{}) as crypto.Signer value in struct literal: interface{} does not implement crypto.Signer (missing method Public)

- cannot use chainCertificates (variable of type []*x509.Certificate) as [][]*x509.Certificate value in struct literal

Comment: @Superleche I updated my answer with an explanation and a working solution, please modify to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. You were a great help. With a little more research and a few minor adjustments, I was able to achieve it.